# Merging entities with identical attributes into one entity

Tags: swift, core-data

My project is a bit longer, so I will try to express my problem with a simpler example project.

Let's say I currently have three entities in my Core Data Model: OneEntity, TwoEntity, and ThreeEntity. Each entity has identical attributes: OneAttribute, TwoAttribute, and ThreeAttribute.

There are three UITableViewControllers: OneTable, TwoTable, and ThreeTable. Each table lists all entries of an entity. OneTable lists all entries of OneEntity, TwoTable lists all entries of TwoEntity, and ThreeTable lists all entries of ThreeEntity.

In each of these tables, the prototype cells use object.valueForKey("OneAttribute"), object.valueForKey("TwoAttribute"), and object.valueForKey("ThreeAttribute") to set values for labels that are put inside of the prototype cell.

I now plan to merge all entities into one entity, MergedEntity, which includes the above-mentioned repeated attributes OneAttribute, TwoAttribute, and ThreeAttribute.

Then, for example, when using object.valueForKey("OneAttribute") in OneTable, how would I only output the entries in MergedEntity that formerly were saved into OneEntity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to merge you should end up with one entity with one attribute, not 3. This entity should also have a 'type' attribute so you can tell what each instance is for.

Now your fetch request uses the 'type' to filter the results for each view controller (replace `"XXX"` with your actual type, which may be a string or an int):

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "type = %@", argumentArray: [ "XXX" ])
```

Comment: I added an attribute that I called "type", but I don't know how to use it. How would an example fetch request look like that filters for a value of type?

Comment: added some more info

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Comment: Only you can mark it as correct as it's your question :)

Comment: Right, just saw and did that :-) Now there's a neat green tick next to your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

Like Wain said, the general way is to add a 'type' attribute to the merged entity. Then there are three more steps that worked in my case:

1) Set a value for the 'type' attribute when saving keys (see last row below).

```
//1
let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

//2
let newPost: NSManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MergedEntity", inManagedObjectContext: context)

//3
newPost.setValue("Test A", forKey: "OneAttribute")
newPost.setValue("Test B", forKey: "TwoAttribute")
newPost.setValue("Test C", forKey: "ThreeAttribute")
newPost.setValue("This is the search String to look for.", forKey: "type")
```

2) Define a predicate constant.

```
let typePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", "type", "This is the search String to look for.")
```

3) Add predicate to fetch request (see last row below).

```
let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
self.managedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("MergedEntity", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
fetchRequest.entity = entity

// Set predicate
fetchRequest.predicate = typePredicate
```

Edit: Wain kindly has added more code. His code combines step 2) and 3) - thank you for your help.